# How can I configure WER to send 32bit dump on 64bit OS to Microsoft?

Tags: c++, debugging, windows-7-x64, windows-error-reporting

In Windows Error Reporting, I have several dump files for a certain hang. When I open the dump, I get an ugly message

```
Debugging a 64-bit dump of a 32-bit process requires full heap information. Please collect a 32-bit dump of a 32-bit process.
```

How can I configure WER to collect and upload the correct dump?

PS: This particular crash happens only on Windows 7 x64. Is there something special about the wow64 emulator on this OS?

Comment: At the time I have researched it [for this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net), LocalDumps created bitness aware dumps.

Comment: *"When I open the dump"* - What tool are you using to inspect the minidump? Not all debuggers provide the same features when it comes to post-mortem debugging (with WinDbg often being the tool of choice).

Comment: @IInspectable: I use both VS and windbg.

Answer (score 0):

You can try setting the `DumpType = 2` if you are using local crash dumps. These settings are in the registry under

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\Windows Error Reporting\LocalDumps
```

This configures the OS to produce a full crash dump. I'm not 100% sure this will help you though.

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb787181(v=vs.85).aspx for more information on local crash dumps (user-mode dumps).

This SO post seems related: [Debugging dump of 32-bit process captured on 64-bit machine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4000420/debugging-dump-of-32-bit-process-captured-on-64-bit-machine)

Also see these blogs: 
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/amb/2011/05/12/do-not-collect-32bit-process-dumps-with-64bit-task-manager/
https://rhauert.wordpress.com/tag/debugging/

I hope some of these can help you.